# CCMenuItemImage - setSelectedImage and setNormal Image

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

Ran across this while working with CCMenuItemImage. It seems like I have to set the SelectedImage and the NormalImage to different CCSprites, otherwise it crashes my application. (I plan on using unique assets later on for both states) CCMenuItemImage *ItemButton; is defined / initialized.

The following does not work:

```
CCSprite *updatedSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"1_button.png"];
[ItemButton setNormalImage:updatedSprite];
[ItemButton setSelectedImage:updatedSprite];
```

The following does work:

```
CCSprite *updatedSpriteNormal = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"1_button.png"];
[ItemButton setNormalImage:updatedSpriteNormal];

CCSprite *updatedSpriteSelected = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"1_button.png"];
[ItemButton setSelectedImage:updatedSpriteSelected];
```

Curious to know why that would happen, I've done some digging but couldn't find anything definitive. Any insight would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you setSelectedImage, the sprite is added as a child to the ItemButton, thus it has a parent. You must create a second instance of CCSprite to setNormalImage, because the node hierarchy of cocos2d will always prevent adding as a child an object that already has a parent.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That makes sense, was just having some difficulty understanding what was going on behind the curtain.